# get referral url of the site in iframe code on that site

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe

`<iframe name='forms_widget' id='forms_widget' src='frame_code.php'></iframe>`
iframe tag above is in site.HTML page.
when the site.HTML file loads frame_code.php file also executes and output is displayed on site.HTML in a div, while in the execution i need referral URL of site.HTML, how is this possible using php.

Comment: First of all.... Eh? Secondly, you can get the referrer using the user agent library https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html

Answer (score 1):

To get the referral URL via php you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

> `$_SERVER`is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations

Php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php